# In Mac OS X 10.11, Opening a VPN connection window with the command line gives me an error

Tags: macos, applescript, osx-elcapitan

On Mac OS X <= 10.10, I could run the following command to open a VPN connection window:

```
function go-vpn {
/usr/bin/env osascript <<-EOF
tell application "System Events"
        tell current location of network preferences
                set VPN to service "LF VPN"
                if exists VPN then connect VPN
                repeat while (current configuration of VPN is not connected)
                    delay 1
                end repeat
        end tell
end tell
EOF
}
```

This would open the connection window (same as selecting the "LF VPN" network from the VPN dropdown). In El Capitan, however, I get the following error:

```
execution error: System Events got an error: Can’t get current configuration of service id "18E8C59B-C186-4669-9F8F-FA67D7AA6E53" of network preferences. (-1728)
```

How would one do the equivalent of this in El Capitan, and how can this be debugged?

[image: Annotated screen shot]

Comment: Hmm, strange, your script works fine on my setup. Could you try running `scutil --nc list` in Terminal? This should give you a list of available network connection services and their ids, maybe the ids differ? For simple troubleshooting, I'd suggest simply deleting and re-creating the VPN entries in System Preferences, too.

Answer (score 16):

I'm using `scutil` instead, and it works flawlessly on OS X 10.11

```
set vpn_name to "'VPN Connection Name'"
set user_name to "my_user_name"
set otp_token to "XYZXYZABCABC"

tell application "System Events"
    set rc to do shell script "scutil --nc status " & vpn_name
    if rc starts with "Connected" then
        do shell script "scutil --nc stop " & vpn_name
    else
        set PWScript to "security find-generic-password -D \"802.1X Password\" -w -a " & user_name
        set passwd to do shell script PWScript
        -- installed through "brew install oath-toolkit"
        set OTPScript to "/usr/local/bin/oathtool --totp --base32 " & otp_token
        set otp to do shell script OTPScript
        do shell script "scutil --nc start " & vpn_name & " --user " & user_name
        delay 2
        keystroke passwd
        keystroke otp
        keystroke return
    end if
end tell
```

Comment: THANKS! I commented out the One Time Password stuff to get mine to work. No keyfob-style data required for my VPN. Otherwise, perfect. Thank you.

Comment: Some password strings can be problematic when you keystroke them all together. I got around this by instead of "keystroke passwd" typing one character of the string at a time:

`repeat with thisCharacter in the characters of passwd
    keystroke thisCharacter
end repeat`

Comment: I actually don't keystroke the password (and otp token) anymore.
It's easier to copy everything to the clipboard through `set the clipboard to passwd & otp` & then paste into the field when it pops up.

Answer (score 10):

```
VPN="YOUR_VPN_NAME"
IS_CONNECTED=$(test -z `scutil --nc status "$VPN" | grep Connected` && echo 0 || echo 1);

if [ $IS_CONNECTED = 1 ]; then
  scutil --nc stop "$VPN"
else
  scutil --nc start "$VPN"
fi
```

Answer (score 5):

use shell script instead:

```
scutil --nc start "$service"    #connect
scutil --nc stop "$service"     #disconnect
```

Answer (score 2):

Further to Oliver's answer, in macOS 10.12.6, the output of `scutil --nc status` has changed so that the match 'Connected' also matches for 'ConnectedCount'. Not sure in which version of macOS this changed.

I've made a slight change to the test to just look at the first line of output, which is really what needs to be checked.

```
VPN="YOUR_VPN_NAME"
IS_CONNECTED=$(test -z `scutil --nc status "$VPN" | head -n 1 | grep Connected` && echo 0 || echo 1);
if [ $IS_CONNECTED = 1 ]; then
  scutil --nc stop "$VPN"
else
  scutil --nc start "$VPN"
fi
```

This works for me on macOs 10.12.6. Hope it helps others.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem:
The issue was I got this error.

```
Can’t get «class svce» "MY VPN" of «class locc» of «class netp» of application "System Events".

System Events got an error: Can’t get service "My VPN" of current location of network preferences. (-1728)
```

The Reason:
I am using IKEv2 services. It seems the Apple Script (which I found all over the internet) fails to work with this. You can find details in the link below.

The solution:
Timac wrote a script to solve this problem. I simply downloaded the precompiled app here.
https://blog.timac.org/2018/0719-vpnstatus/

If you are interested in the source code that makes it work, you can find it on GitHub here: https://github.com/Timac/VPNStatus

You can also dig deeper into the problem if you are that sort of person on that link. It gives details.

If you are simply looking for a solution to Auto Connect your VPN, the VPNstatus app worked for me.